# Find the median individual with observations on multiple variables over time

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, median

I have a question regarding the use of median. We collected data concerning disease development on hosts. We gathered the evolution of three variables over time on individuals. Their characteristics:

1. three variables: A=f(time), B=f(time), C=f(time). A, B and C are the quantity of different symptoms, expressed as the percentage of a skin area. A=45% means that the 45% of the skin area is covered with symptom "a".
2. The skin is covered with symptoms, symptoms don't cover another. At any time A+B+C=100%.
3. sample were made of n=20 individuals,
4. there was 15 measurement dates (so "time" is 15 dates).

I am also interested in calculating the median rather than the mean (since it is less prone to drift with extreme values). More precisely, I'd like to identify a "median individual" in my sample of 20, i.e., an individual that has a median quantity of symptoms, and reflecting the evolution of the entire population. It's a common practice in my field, but it's not that easy in my case (see below), and biologists I contacted don't know the method.

The question is, how to find this median individual? Since I have two difficulties ahead:

- three variables (A, B, C). As I know it, the median should be calculated on only one of these variables (and the choice of the variable will be arbitrary, biologically speaking). Perhaps there is a way to calculate the median on more than one variable? A sort of centroid of medians.
- variables over multiple measurement dates. At what date should I calculate the median? No date seems more relevant than the others (again, choice will be arbitrary). One solution could be to calculate, for each individual, the integral of the symptom curve (in my field it's called Area Under the Disease Progress Curve, i.e. AUDPC). Then I choose the median AUDPC among individuals. Would you advise another solution?

Comment: You are right, thanks for your remark (and sorry for the mistakes). I edited the post. So much for working under heavy doses of theine.

Comment: Do the 3 symptoms always = 100% (there is no symptom-free skin)? For the purposes of this process, are you thinking of A, B, & C as response variables?

Comment: With only 20 individuals, is there some reason why you can't just show complete data for all of them? Variability of disease development among individuals may be as important as the median progression of disease.

Comment: @gung: No symptom-free skin indeed (edited). A, B, C are response variables.

Comment: @EdM: n=20 per treatment, but I have 24 treatments. So too much data to show (even if we check the data of every individual). Variability may be important, esp. because despite huge standardization of protocol we always end up with "extreme" individuals.

Comment: Is there some natural ordering of A, B, and C with respect to severity of disease or some other characteristic?

Comment: If you have 24 treatments, what is it you want to identify a median individual for? Do you ultimately want to test if the treatments differ? Do you want to be able to predict what will happen w/ a given treatment in the future? Do you want to characterize the (multivariate) response distributions associated w/ different treatments?

Comment: @EdM: Temporally speaking, yes. A turns into B that turns into C. More precisely, on skin area, it is: "A" then "A+B" then "A+B+C" then "B+C" then "C". I don't know it it helps, if you think it does I can edit the post + add an example of curves.

Comment: @gung: (I edited my previous comment) the median individual would be useful for various reasons: i)to draw + discuss the curves, ii)to use the median individual for comparisons (e.g. "ABC of median individual vs. otherstuff", iii)compare treatments and iv)get estimates for the differents parameters (treatments).

Comment: The thing is, you wouldn't use the median person to test if the treatments differ or to estimate parameters. Both of those would be done w/ the full data (& w/o explicitly using the median in any way). You could use the median for communication / illustration, though.